# How a class extension works as a means of implementing private methods

Tags: objective-c, categories, objective-c-category, class-extensions

I believe a popular way to declare "private methods" in Objective-C is to create its *class extension* and declare methods that you would like to make as private.

I would like to know more in detail on how an *class extension* makes the methods work as private.

- Update: I asked this question with the term *empty category* which is incorrect. I now changed it as *class extension*

Comment: They’re not called empty categories: they’re called [class extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html). Also, note that there’s no such thing as private methods in Objective-C — the runtime will happily invoke a class extension method if the corresponding message is sent in an arbitrary implementation file.

Comment: Right, so to make sure, I doubled quoted private methods. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an "empty category", it's a [class extension](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/).  Read  Bbum's explanation of them at the link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you create your empty category in your implementation file, not your header file so other classes can't access it.

```
//TestClass.h

@interface TestClass : NSObject 
{
}

-(void)publicMethod;

@end

//TestClass.m

@interface TestClass()

-(void)privateMethod;

@end

@implementation TestClass

-(void)publicMethod
{
NSLog (@"public");
}

-(void)privateMethod
{
NSLog (@"private");
}

@end
```