# XCode 4.2 why do I see @interface both inside .h and .m files

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

why do I see @interface twice( inside .h and .m files in this UIViewController files I've created. the one in the .m seems to be like a constructor. is it?

.h file

```
@interface BlackTimer : UIViewController 


@end
```

.m file

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between @interface definition in .h and .m file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967187/difference-between-interface-definition-in-h-and-m-file)

Answer (score 7):

usually in the .m file you put all the declarations for private methods

it's a good use to write the word "private" (or something similar) like this:

```
@interface ViewController (private)

-(void)myPrivateMethod;

@end
```

Comment: Here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452445/how-a-class-extension-works-as-a-means-of-implementing-private-methods> is another SO question related to your comment.

Comment: Better: no name for that category at all, as you will have a class extension than, what will work better with the compiler. see qegals answer.

Answer (score 7):

The @interface in the .m file is called a class extension. [Here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/) is a good link explaining it. Hope this helps.
And [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) is the Apple documentation on class extensions.

Answer (score -1):

The `@interface ViewController ()` definition in the implementation file (.m) is an anonymous Category. It allows to define ivars, properties and messages your class implements without exposing them to other objects importing your public interface (.h).